# Test linear independence of a set using derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra

> > Is the set $\{1, e^x+e^{-x}, e^x-e^{-x}\}$ linearly independent.

**Question:** Can I use derivatives to solve this? I'm thinking something like this:

In order for the set to be independent then:

$r + s(e^{x}+e^{-x})+t(e^{x}-e^{-x}) = 0$ if and only if $r$, $s$, and $t$ are equal to $0$.

So,

$r + s(e^{x}+e^{-x})+t(e^{x}-e^{-x}) = 0$

$r + se^{x}+se^{-x}+te^{x}-te^{-x} = 0$

$r + (s+t)e^{x}+(s-t)e^{-x} = 0$

Here I take the derivative and:

$(s+t)e^{x}-(s-t)e^{-x} = 0$

Then, adding last two equations

r+ 2(s-t) = 0

Which shows that the set is not linearly indepent (if I take same values for s and t then equation is 0 (but not s nor t are 0).

Is this reasoning right or am I way two wrong. I'm trying to self-study linear algebra but this is pretty damn hard!

Comment: Dont forget that $r$ is a constant, so $d/dx(r) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\,a,b,c\in\Bbb R\,$:

$$a+b(e^x+e^{-x})+c(e^x-e^{-x})=0\iff a+e^x(b+c)+e^{-x}(b-c)=0$$

Choosing $\,x=0\,$ we get

$$a+b+c+b-c=0\iff a+2b=0$$

Choosing $\,x=1\,$:

$$\text{I}\;\;\;\;\;\;a+e(b+c)+e^{-1}(b-c)=0$$

Choosing $\,x=-1\,$:

$$\text{II}\;\;\;\;\;\;a+e^{-1}(b+c)+e(b-c)=0$$

Substract II from I:

$$2c(e-e^{-1})=0\Longrightarrow c=0$$

Try to take it from and show that also $\,a=b=0\,$ and thus the three functions are line. independent.

Comment: Nice and easy, your solution is the most easy to follow for a newbie like me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not. But you can reason as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
r + s (e^x + e^{-x}) + t (e^x - e^{-x}) &= 0 \\
r + (s + t) e^x + (s - t) e^{-x}        &= 0
\end{align*}
$$
Now, for $x = 0$ you have $r + 2 s = 0$. Try again with $x = 1$ and $x = -1$
(i.e., three easy values), and you get three equations in the three unknowns $r$, $s$ and $t$. You'll find that the only solution is $r = s = t = 0$, i.e., they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, derivatives can be a very useful tool to test for linear independence. For some details, you may want to read about the [Wronskian.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian)

Let's use differentiation efficiently to deal with your functions.

Suppose that $f(x)=r+s(e^x+e^{-x})+t(e^x-e^{-x})\equiv 0$. Differentiate. We get $f'(x)= s(e^x-e^{-x})+t(e^x+e^{-x})\equiv 0$. Set $x=0$. We get $2t=0$, and therefore $t=0$.

Differentiate **again**, and set $x=0$. We get $s=0$. Finally, since $s=0$ and $t=0$, by setting $x=0$ in the equation $f(x)=0$, we get $r=0$.

Comment: You can see the Wronskian approach [*here*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det+%7B%7B1%2C+e%5Ex%2Be%5E%28-x%29%2C+e%5Ex-e%5E%28-x%29%7D%2C%7B0%2C+e%5Ex-e%5E%28-x%29%2C+e%5Ex%2Be%5E%28-x%29%7D%2C%7B0%2C+e%5Ex%2Be%5E%28-x%29%2C+e%5Ex-e%5E%28-x%29%7D%7D) for this problem.

Comment: @Amzoti I'm sorry I don't understand what a determinant = 4 means. Can you please explain me

Comment: @Amzoti Reading now. Actually, determinants appear on the next lecture (MIT OCW) thanks :)

Comment: @Susana: Andre' provided a nice link to the Wronskian. If you setup the determinant as shown [*here*](http://www.solitaryroad.com/c287.html), you can see how to set it up. It columns are made up of $(f, f', f'')$ and if the det is nonzero for all x, they are independent. There are also some other conditions that can apply, but you can read those on the web page. Got it? Note, the det is not zero for all values of $x$. I meant independent :-). It is good to know how you approached it too - approach was ok, but when the number of functions add up, the Wronskian is the way to go.